# Why does this selector not work

Tags: css, css-selectors

Given the following markup

```html
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="clmn2">
    </div>
    <div class="clmn2">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the information given on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3anot)

By my interpretation this selector should work.

```css
*:not(.fixed) [class*="clmn"]
```

Unfortunately it does not, however this does.

```css
div:not(.fixed) [class*="clmn"]
```

Any ideas why?

***Update ***

If you check the linked [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sVpTA/) the column in rows not marked with the class fixed should be floated.

Comment: Define "does not work". It certainly [looks like it works](http://jsfiddle.net/gEgMN/).

Comment: It works, I am not sure why you are having that issue. Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xZQ7W/1/

Comment: What node do you wish to select with this?

Comment: @TravisJ Your fiddle is doing the opposite of what I would expect. The divs with class `.clmn2` should not be blue. I've added an example. @Micea I want it to be node agnostic.

Comment: I think it may be a bug in all browsers (though that is hard to believe so maybe I'm misunderstanding). The spec uses the example of *:not(FOO) to mean " all but FOO elements" but that doesn’t work: http://jsfiddle.net/rq5At/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*:not(.fixed) foo` matches

> A foo element that is a descendant of any element that is not a member of the fixed class

This is different to:

> A foo element that is not a descendant of any element that is a member of the fixed class

If we had:

```
<a class="fixed">
  <b>
    <foo></foo>
  </b>
</a>
```

Then the foo element is a descendant of a `b` element that is not a member of the fixed class. (It is *also* a descendant of an `a` element that **is** a member of that class, but that doesn't matter because `*:not(.fixed)` will happily match the `b` element instead.)

Comment: I actually cannot believe I didn't think of that.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3):

Your "bad" selector matches any element with a class as given *that is a descendant of any element without class `fixed`*.

Since both the `<html>` and `<body>` elements do not have the class `fixed` and your inner `<div>`s *are* their descendants, the selector matches them.

The "good" selector only considers descendants of any `<div>` that does not have the class `fixed`. Since the only `<div>` in your HTML that has descendants also has that class, the selector matches nothing.

In general, plain `:not(whatever)` followed by a descendant combinator is not really useful. In your case it looks like the solution would be to replace the "descendant" combinator with the child combinator `>`:

```
:not(.fixed) > [class*="clmn"]
```

Comment: Of course! I didn't think about it cascading from the body etc! You were beaten to the punch but have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is too general. Since `*` will also select things like body. And body is `not(.fixed)`, the rule will still be applied.

Change it to something more specific like `.row:not(.fixed)`.

http://jsfiddle.net/sVpTA/2/

#### CSS

```
.row:not(.fixed) [class*="clmn"]{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: That's actually exactly what the selector is now.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's working better than you want it to.

`*:not(.fixed)` matches, among other things, your `body` element.  Eventually, somewhere within the body, it finds your `clm*` divs, and applies the styles.

If you only want to match things that are `direct` descendants of something non-fixed, use:

```
 *:not(.fixed) > [class*="clmn"] { /* ... */ }
```

Which does work.